# A form for a piecewise continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions, piecewise-continuity

$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$Take any $D \subseteq \rr$. Is it true that for any piecewise continuous function $f : D \to \rr$ there is an infinitely differentiable continuous function $g : D \to \rr$ and a piecewise constant function $h : D \to \rr$ and an infinitely differentiable continuous function $i : \rr^2 \to \rr$ such that $f(x) = i(g(x),h(x))$ for every $x \in D$?

Comment: I think I know what you're asking, and it's an interesting question, so I've rewritten your question. See if that's what you want. I think letting $f(x) = \frac1{1-x+\lfloor x \rfloor}$ for every $x \in \rr$ gives a counter-example, but I'm a bit lazy to prove it.

Comment: $D$ is simply the domain. You didn't specify it so I made it as general as possible. Any more specific domain such as an interval is going to be equivalent, so there's no harm in having an arbitrary domain. As for your idea, yes the issue is having a point where $f$ is continuous from one side but tends to infinity on the other side. Then I think no amount of manipulating continuous functions and piecewise constant functions can create it, basically because any continuous function is bounded on any closed interval.

Comment: Then add a sentence saying precisely what you said in your above comment: `I was attempting to determine a possible usage for it (beyond the obvious use; removing discontinuity from troubling graphs).` This is context that is missing from your question. Also, don't assume that the close reason is accurate. If 3 people choose "unclear" and 2 choose "no context" then only the majority reason is shown. Also, people are quite likely to choose "unclear" for the original question even if they also think there was "no context provided". Anyway, editing it again will let more people see it again.

Comment: You should say what definition of "piecewise continuous" you use. In the definition I grew up with, the piecewise continuous functions are precisely the functions of the form $g + h$ with $g$ continuous and $h$ piecewise constant. Apparently the answerer and @user21820 use a different definition.

Comment: Way to go, @TheGreatDuck. Completely failing to understand the mathematical content, and then adding a gratuitous insult. Point 1, there is _always_ a different definition. If there is not yet one, that won't last long. Point 2, The definition I grew up with is equivalent to the one you give (unless you allow infinite one-sided limits, then the definition I'm used to is more restrictive). But user21820 and Milo Brandt suggest putative counterexamples, so they seem to be using a different definition.

Comment: You just need to consider the jumps of the function, and use those to get the piecewise constant function. With $\varphi(x) = x\cdot \lfloor x\rfloor$, we have $\lim_{x \to n^+} \varphi(x) = n^2$ and $\lim_{x \to n^-} \varphi(x) = n(n-1) = n^2-n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $\varphi$ has a jump of height $n$ at $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\varphi$ is right-continuous, our piecewise constant function will also be right-continuous. We can choose one value arbitrarily, so let's choose $h(0) = 0$ [that gives the simplest form]. For $x > 0$, $h(x)$ will be the sum of all jumps between $0$ and $x$,

Comment: that is $1 + 2 + \dotsc + \lfloor x\rfloor = \frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)$. For $x < 0$, $h(x)$ will be the negative of the jumps between $x$ and $0$, that is, of $(-1) + (-2) + \dotsc + (\lfloor x\rfloor + 1) = -\frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor(\lfloor x\rfloor + 1)$. Ho, cool, we have $h(x) = \frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor (\lfloor x\rfloor + 1)$ for all $x$. And now we define $g(x) := \varphi(x) - h(x) = x\lfloor x\rfloor - \frac{1}{2}\lfloor x\rfloor(\lfloor x\rfloor + 1)$. Check that $g$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does not work. In particular, let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }x\leq 0 \\ 1/x&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}$$
This function cannot be written in your form. To prove this, consider that, as $g$ is piecewise constant, there must be some interval of the form $(0,c)$ on which it is constant. Thus $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}g(x)$ exists. Since $h$ is continuous, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}h(x)$ exists as well. Since $i$ is continuous and both these limits exist, we have that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}i(g(x),h(x))$ exists. However, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$ does not exist, so $f(x)$ and $i(g(x),h(x))$ are not everywhere equal.

More generally, what this tells us is that if $f$ is a piecewise continuous function where one of its pieces cannot be continuously extended to a closed interval, then $f$ cannot be of this form - so a bounded example of such an $f$ is
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }x\leq 0 \\ \sin(1/x)&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}.$$

Conversely, if each piece of $f$ can be continuously extended onto a closed interval, then it is relatively trivial to produce the suitable form. In particular, suppose the pieces of $f$ are the intervals $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ and $f_k$ is a continuous function $\overline{I_k}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ where $\overline{I_k}$ is the closure of $I_k$. Extend each $f_k$ continuous to a function $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ by making it a constant function extending from either endpoint of the interval. Then, if you choose $\delta_{i}(x)$ to be some continuous function* which is $1$ at $i$ and $0$ for any other $x\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, we may write
$$g(x)=x$$
$$\text{if }x\in I_k\text{ then }h(x)=k$$
$$i(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)\delta_i(y)$$
which is clearly correct, since in the interval $I_k$, we have that only $\delta_k(h(x))$ is non-zero, and hence the sum reduces to one term which is just $f_k(x)$, which agrees with $f$ on $I_k$.

(*There are plenty of choices for $\delta$. One would be to just use the Lagrange polynomial associated with our constraints, which is $\delta_i(x)=\frac{\prod_{k=1,k\neq i}^n(x-k)}{\prod_{k=1,k\neq i}^n(i-k)}$. Other choices would be tent maps, or shifted versions of $\operatorname{sinc}$.)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck What's your definition of "piecewise continuous"? The function $\sin(1/x)$ is a continuous function $(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R$. Perhaps you're troubled by the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\sin(1/x)$ doesn't exist, but note that the definition of continuity says nothing about points not in the domain, so it doesn't matter. In general, continuous functions can behave badly near open "edges" of the domain.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Yes, but each *piece* of a piecewise function has a domain less than $\mathbb R$ - the two pieces here are $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0]$. Again, could you provide a precise definition of "piecewise continuous" that you wish to use? (Also, your last edit to the question significantly changes it - this is in general frowned upon on M.SE. Also, it brings in easy counterexamples, since if $g$ and $i$ are infinitely differentiable, then $i(g(x),h(x))$ is piecewise infinitely differentiable, which $f$ might not be)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I don't think that's standard usage - if you define it that way, then my answer starting at "conversely" applies and gives an affirmative answer, as that is equivalent to asking that the pieces be extendable to closed intervals. (Well, sort of - as long as the jumps happen on a discrete set). On the other hand, the most liberal definition is just "continuous on each set of a finite partition", which my answer addresses. (To be honest, "piecewise continuous" is not the most consistently defined term - it's rarely a main point of discussion in my experience)